# What statement is missing on My VBS? I can't find it. It says statement in 41 line is missing

Tags: vbscript

```
X=inputbox("Hello there (Hello/Hi/What's up?)")

If X = "Hello" Then

   X=inputbox("What's up?? (Feeling Awesome/Feeling Normal/Feeling Sad)")

ElseIf X = "hello" Then

   X=inputbox("What's up?? (Feeling Awesome/Feeling Normal/Feeling Sad)")

ElseIf X = "Hi" Then

   X=inputbox("What's up?? (Feeling Awesome/Feeling Normal/Feeling Sad)")

ElseIf X = "hi" Then

   X=inputbox("What's up?? (Feeling Awesome/Feeling Normal/Feeling Sad)")

End If

If X = "Feeling Awesome" Then

   X=inputbox("Great! Can we play Question and Answer with Yes and No? 
(Yes/No)?")

ElseIf X = "Feeling Normal" Then

   X=inputbox("Okay! Can we play Question and Answer with Yes and No? 
(Yes/No)?")

ElseIf X = "Feeling Sad" Then

   X=inputbox("Oh no! Maybe playing a game will make you happy. Can we play 
Question and Answer with Yes and No? (Yes/No)?")

ElseIf X = "feeling awesome" Then

   X=inputbox("Great! Can we play Question and Answer with Yes and No? 
(Yes/No)?")

ElseIf X = "feeling normal" Then

   X=inputbox("Okay! Can we play Question and Answer with Yes and No? 
(Yes/No)?")

ElseIf X - "feeling sad" Then

   X=inputbox("Oh no! Maybe playing a game will make you happy. Can we play 
Question and Answer with Yes and No? (Yes/No)?")

End If

If X = "Yes" Then

B=Msgbox("Do you have secrets?",vbYesNo+vbQuestion)

If B = vbYes Then

B=MsgBox("Are they super secrets that only you know, Or they also know your best 

friend(s)?",vbYesNo+vbQuestion)

ElseIf B = vbNo Then

B=MsgBox("Great that means you are a nice guy.",vbInformation)

B = MsgBox("Do you have a Sister/Brother?",vbYesNo+vbQuestion)

If B = vbYes Then

A = inputbox("What's his/her name?")

B = msgbox("From now my favorite name is" + A)

ElseIf B = vbNo Then

B = MsgBox ("Okay then!")

B = MsgBox("Is Ice Cream better than Chocolate?",vbYesNo+vbQuestion)

If B = vbYes Then

B = MsgBox("But for me chocolates are much better")

ElseIf B = vbNo Then

B = MsgBox("Cool I like for me chocolates are better too.")

EndIf

ElseIf Y = vbNo Then

msgBox("Bye!")

EndIf
```

Comment: Indent the code, and the answer should appear. It looks like you're opening more "if" than you are closing.

Comment: [`Select Case-End Select`](https://ss64.com/vb/select.html) would be easier

Comment: What exactly is `ElseIf X - "feeling sad" Then` might to accomplish, is it meant to be `ElseIf X = "feeling sad" Then` perhaps? Without a condition that evaluates to a boolean the statement is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is the incorrect condition;

```
ElseIf X - "feeling sad" Then
```

This is an incomplete statement because an `If` statement condition needs to evaluate to a Boolean *(`True` or `False`)* result.

Try fixing the statement;

```
ElseIf X = "feeling sad" Then
```

Will likely give you a

> Expected End

error due to the [reason pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48802346/692942) by [@Ekkehard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603855/ekkehard-horner)

Comment: Ugh! I always type - except =

Answer (score 1):

Try to indent your code with this tool online : http://www.vbindent.com/

for better reading and debugging your issue :

```
X=inputbox("Hello there (Hello/Hi/What's up?)")
If X = "Hello" Then
    X=inputbox("What's up?? (Feeling Awesome/Feeling Normal/Feeling Sad)")
ElseIf X = "hello" Then
    X=inputbox("What's up?? (Feeling Awesome/Feeling Normal/Feeling Sad)")
ElseIf X = "Hi" Then
    X=inputbox("What's up?? (Feeling Awesome/Feeling Normal/Feeling Sad)")
ElseIf X = "hi" Then
    X=inputbox("What's up?? (Feeling Awesome/Feeling Normal/Feeling Sad)")
End If
If X = "Feeling Awesome" Then
    X=inputbox("Great! Can we play Question and Answer with Yes and No? (Yes/No)?")
ElseIf X = "Feeling Normal" Then
    X=inputbox("Okay! Can we play Question and Answer with Yes and No? (Yes/No)?")
ElseIf X = "Feeling Sad" Then
    X=inputbox("Oh no! Maybe playing a game will make you happy. Can we play Question and Answer with Yes and No? (Yes/No)?")
ElseIf X = "feeling awesome" Then
    X=inputbox("Great! Can we play Question and Answer with Yes and No? (Yes/No)?")
ElseIf X = "feeling normal" Then
    X=inputbox("Okay! Can we play Question and Answer with Yes and No? (Yes/No)?")
ElseIf X - "feeling sad" Then
    X=inputbox("Oh no! Maybe playing a game will make you happy. Can we play Question and Answer with Yes and No? (Yes/No)?")
End If

If X = "Yes" Then
    B=Msgbox("Do you have secrets?",vbYesNo+vbQuestion)
    If B = vbYes Then
        B=MsgBox("Are they super secrets that only you know, Or they also know your best friend(s)?",vbYesNo+vbQuestion)
    ElseIf B = vbNo Then
        B=MsgBox("Great that means you are a nice guy.",vbInformation)
        B = MsgBox("Do you have a Sister/Brother?",vbYesNo+vbQuestion)
    End If
    If B = vbYes Then
        A = inputbox("What's his/her name?")
        B = msgbox("From now my favorite name is" + A)
    ElseIf B = vbNo Then
        B = MsgBox ("Okay then!")
        B = MsgBox("Is Ice Cream better than Chocolate?",vbYesNo+vbQuestion)
    End If  
    If B = vbYes Then
        B = MsgBox("But for me chocolates are much better")
    ElseIf B = vbNo Then
        B = MsgBox("Cool I like for me chocolates are better too.")             
    ElseIf Y = vbNo Then    
        msgBox("Bye!")  
    End If
End If
```

Comment: How does this solve the issue, the missing / incomplete statement is still present `ElseIf X - "feeling sad" Then`??

Answer (score 1):

It's `End If` not `EndIf` and (in your case) each `If` needs an `End If`. Indenting carefully would help to determine where to add those missing `End Ifs`. I doubt that a 'mechanical' indenter will format the code in the way you intended.

**Update wrt speculations about what code causes what error:**

```
48800410-1.vbs

If X Then
   WScript.Echo "EndIf throws 'Expected statement' error"
EndIf

output:

cscript 48800410-1.vbs
...\48800410-1.vbs(3, 1) Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected statement

48800410-2.vbs

If False Then
   WScript.Echo "Trying to substract string throws a type mismatch error"
ElseIf X - "feeling sad" Then
   WScript.Echo "xxx"
End If

cscript 48800410-2.vbs
...\48800410-2.vbs(3, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Type mismatch: '[string: "feeling sad"]'
```

The compilation error must be corrected before the runtime error can occur.

Comment: This would produce an "Expected End" or "Block If without End If" errors.

Comment: But worth noting the `EndIf` would also cause it to fail.

Comment: Maybe it's the combination of an `If...ElseIf X - ""....EndIf` together? *(the missing space in `EndIf` is deliberate)*.